# Can individual values or entire rows be copied directly between Excel VBA arrays?

Tags: arrays, vba, excel

I'm new to VBA and programming in general (and stack overflow). I have a workbook with three worksheets. I'm trying to compare a list of values in column 1 of a table on one sheet with column 2 of a large data table on another. If they match, I want to copy that row to a table on a third sheet. I had this working without arrays (similar loops, working on sheets/ranges directly), but it was way too slow and, though it usually completed successfully, it often brought Excel to its knees in the process, so I went to arrays.

I managed to get the source data and lookup values into arrays, and I can loop through the arrays and retrieved the expected data in any individual cell (I've been using the intermediate window and debug.print to check variables and details about the array values).

I just can't figure out the last few pieces. For each matching row I'm trying to copy each cell from the data array to the target array. When the target array is populated I want to dump it into a table on a third worksheet.

I'm getting a runtime 424 object required error here:

```
TargetArray(k, j) = DataArray(i, j).Value
```

I could write each value in the TargetArray directly back to the target sheet, but this seems no faster than the no-array way.

Once I can do that I was going to do this, which I believe will work:

```
TargetArray = DataArray
```

I have spent days on this and done hundreds of searches and lots of reading to get to this point, but I'm stumped.

1. Is there any trick that wil allow me to write an individual value from one array to another?
2. If not, how can rows be copied from one table to another without touching the worksheet thousands of times? (aka "how would someone who knows what they're doing approach this?")

No doubt my code has unneeded steps and other issues. All suggestions are appreciated.

Here's all of the code:

```
Option Explicit
Option Base 1
Sub CopyMatchingRows()
Dim DataArray() As Variant, CriteriaArray() As Variant, TargetArray As Variant
Dim DataRange As Range, CriteriaRange As Range, TargetRange As Range
Dim rCountData As Integer, rCountCriteria As Integer, rCountTarget As Integer 'row counts
Dim cCountData As Integer, cCountCriteria As Integer, cCountTarget As Integer 'col counts

Dim LookupValue As Variant 'lookup value

Dim h As Integer, i As Integer, j As Integer, k As Integer 'counters

'define ranges from tables
Set DataRange = Worksheets("SourceData").ListObjects("DataTable").Range
Set CriteriaRange = Worksheets("SchoolList").ListObjects("SchoolListTable").Range
Set TargetRange = Worksheets("SchoolData").ListObjects("SchoolDataTable").DataBodyRange

'turn screen updating back on
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

'clear target range contents
'TargetRange.ClearContents

'define row and column count variables
rCountData = DataRange.Rows.Count
rCountCriteria = CriteriaRange.Rows.Count
rCountTarget = TargetRange.Rows.Count
cCountData = DataRange.Columns.Count
cCountCriteria = CriteriaRange.Columns.Count
cCountTarget = TargetRange.Columns.Count

'dimension arrays
ReDim DataArray(rCountData, cCountData)
ReDim CriteriaArray(rCountCriteria, cCountCriteria)


'dump ranges to arrays
DataArray = DataRange
TargetArray = TargetRange
CriteriaArray = CriteriaRange

'reset k value and target array
k = 1
ReDim TargetArray(UBound(DataArray, 2), k)


'loop through list of lookup values and define LookupValue
 For h = 1 To UBound(CriteriaArray, 1)
    LookupValue = CriteriaRange(h, 1)

   'loop through data area comparing column 2 to LookupValue
     For i = 2 To UBound(DataArray, 1)
        If DataArray(i, 2) = LookupValue Then
        k = k + 1 'increment number of rows needed
        ReDim Preserve TargetArray(UBound(DataArray, 2), k) 'resize TargetArray to match

        'loop through each column of matching row and copy to TargetArray
         For j = 1 To UBound(DataArray, 2)
            TargetArray(k, j) = DataArray(i, j).Value

        Next j
        End If

     Next i
 Next h

'one all matching rows are added to TargetArray, copy back to worksheet table
TargetRange = TargetArray

'turn screen updating back on
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Arrays don't have a `value` property, so `TargetArray(k, j) = DataArray(i, j).Value` should be `TargetArray(k, j) = DataArray(i, j)`

Comment: Also, `Redim Preserve` is a slow operation.  It's better to oversize the array initially, and only `Redim Preservce` once at the end to reduce it to the actually used size

Comment: Another point: you don't need to set the array sizes before moving the Range data into them.  Eg `DataArray = DataRange` will set the size of the array to match the range

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cause of your error is that arrays don't have a value property, so `TargetArray(k, j) = DataArray(i, j).Value` should be `TargetArray(k, j) = DataArray(i, j)`

Also, there a several opertunities to improve performance of the code.  See inline comments

```
Sub CopyMatchingRows()
    Dim Data() As Variant, CriteriaArray() As Variant, TargetArray As Variant
    Dim DataRange As Range, CriteriaRange As Range, TargetRange As Range
 '   Dim rCountData As Integer, rCountCriteria As Integer, rCountTarget As Integer 'row counts
 '   Dim cCountData As Integer, cCountCriteria As Integer, cCountTarget As Integer 'col counts

    Dim LookupValue As Variant 'lookup value

    Dim h As Long, i As Long, j As Long, k As Long 'counters  <~~~ Use Longs

    'define ranges from tables
    Set DataRange = Worksheets("SourceData").ListObjects("DataTable").Range
    Set CriteriaRange = Worksheets("SchoolList").ListObjects("SchoolListTable").Range
    Set TargetRange = Worksheets("SchoolData").ListObjects("SchoolDataTable").DataBodyRange

    'turn screen updating back on
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    'clear target range contents
    'TargetRange.ClearContents

    '<~~~ dont need these
    'define row and column count variables
'    rCountData = DataRange.Rows.Count
'    rCountCriteria = CriteriaRange.Rows.Count
'    rCountTarget = TargetRange.Rows.Count
'    cCountData = DataRange.Columns.Count
'    cCountCriteria = CriteriaRange.Columns.Count
'    cCountTarget = TargetRange.Columns.Count

    '<~~~ dont need these
    'dimension arrays
'    ReDim DataArray(rCountData, cCountData)
'    ReDim CriteriaArray(rCountCriteria, cCountCriteria)


    'dump ranges to arrays  ~~~~ .Value is not necassary but adds clarity
    DataArray = DataRange.Value
    TargetArray = TargetRange.Value
    CriteriaArray = CriteriaRange.Value

    'reset k value and target array
    k = 1
    ReDim TargetArray(1 To UBound(DataArray, 2), 1 To UBound(CriteriaArray, 1) * UBound(DataArray, 1)) ' <~~~ max possible siz)


    'loop through list of lookup values and define LookupValue
     For h = 1 To UBound(CriteriaArray, 1)
        LookupValue = CriteriaRange(h, 1)

       'loop through data area comparing column 2 to LookupValue
         For i = 2 To UBound(DataArray, 1)
            If DataArray(i, 2) = LookupValue Then
                k = k + 1 'increment number of rows needed
                '<~~~ defer this
                'ReDim Preserve TargetArray(1 To UBound(DataArray, 2), k) 'resize TargetArray to match

                'loop through each column of matching row and copy to TargetArray
                For j = 1 To UBound(DataArray, 2)
                    TargetArray(k, j) = DataArray(i, j) '.Value
                Next j
            End If

         Next i
     Next h

    'once all matching rows are added to TargetArray, copy back to worksheet table
    ' <~~~ reduce to actual used size
    ReDim Preserve TargetArray(1 To UBound(TargetArray, 1), 1 To k)
    TargetRange = TargetArray

    'turn screen updating back on
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks! With your two ReDims I was getting subscript out of range errors so I switched them to 
`TargetArray(1 To UBound(DataArray, 1), 1 To UBound(DataArray, 2))` (target will be subset of data in my case) and `TargetArray(1 To UBound(TargetArray, 1), 1 To k)`. Works great now, but the final size of TargetArray is 3706x179 (k = 179). Should be 179x63 (63 is column count in both source and target). I tried switching things around, transposing, etc, and can't figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

you could try to do with an `AdvancedFilter` Method, is easier and fast.

```
Sub Match_Data()  

'' Declare Variables
Dim WksT as Worksheet

'' Set Variables
Set WksT = Worksheet("SchoolData")

'' First delete the previous table to avoid errors
Call DeleteTable(WksT,"SchoolDataTable")

'' Filter table
Range("SchoolListTable[#All]").AdvancedFilter _ '' Select Named Table
                        Action:=xlFilterCopy, _ '' How to filter
                        '' Select field to filter, in this case 
                        '' i'm assuming that the field name is "School"
                        CriteriaRange:=Range("DataTable[[#All],[School]]"), _  
                        CopyToRange:= WksT.Range("A1"), _ '' Where to put data
                        Unique:=False

'' Convert Range to named table 
WksT.ListObjects.Add(xlSrcRange,  _
                       WksT.Range("A1", WksT.Range("A1").End(xlToRight).End(xlDown)), , _  
                        xlYes).Name = "SchoolDataTable"

End Sub
```

**Sub to delete table**

```
Private Sub DeleteTable(Wks As Worksheet, sName As String)
'' This is to avoid if the table not exists
On Error GoTo errHdlr
Dim oLObj As ListObject

Set oLObj = Wks.ListObjects(sName)
oLObj.Delete

Exit Sub
errHdlr:
    Resume Next
End Sub
```

*If you need to drop easy an array in a `Range` use `Resize`*

```
    '' Is "+ 1" if the array start at 0
    Range("A1").Resize(UBound(TargetArray) + 1, 1) = Application.Transpose(TargetArray)
```